# add custom document class in lyx

Tags: lyx, templates, lyx-layouts

I downloaded the template of latex and I am trying to import it in lyx for use
where the template has these files like shown in the image and without file .layout
[image]

I added them to layout in directory
[image]
and I did Reconfigure LyX from `Tools -> Reconfigure`
then Restart LyX but I didn't see the ducoment class when use this `Document -> Settings -> Document Class`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: yes, it answers my question but the way is complex because I don't have a .layout file ,all of thanks